# The explanation of use of random color

Tags: javascript

```
function rndm_colour(){
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color
}
```

This is in my lesson. When I changed the number of 6 in i < 6 with 7 or higher numbers, the code does not work. Why? what is number 6 mean?

Comment: If you are happy with one of the answers below, you can "accept" one of them. To do this, click on the tick/check mark next to that answer, so that it changes colour (turns green). It is not mandatory to do this, but it is a nice way to thank people who have helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Six digits represent RGB color(2 Red, 2 Green, 2 Blue). The maximum value of RGB is 255 (ff in hexadecimal). Thats why the maximum value of a color is #ffffff(100% red, 100% green, 100% blue)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is producing a HEX color, which is defined as a `#` followed by 6 hexadecimal values (0 - 9, A-F). A 7th hexadecimal would produce an invalid color value

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that color is a Hexadecimal representation of RGB (Red, Green, Blue).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color

> The function should also work with 8, since 8 characters since that defines RGBA (Red, Green, Blue, Alpha (transparency)) - https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa

Answer (score 0):

In your code the color is produced in hex value which is of 6 digits like (#00ffff, #123456) and if you change I to 7 it get wrong because a 7 digit hex code is not valid (#1234567) will output nothing. Here number 6 mean get random number 6 time and put # with it

You can try this to test:

```
<input type="color" value="#123456">// it will output a color because it is 6 digit

<input type="color" value="#1234567">// it will output not output a color because it is 7 digit
```